# How to get parent name from subcategories Woocommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

When I try to get the name of a parent, I am getting an error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

in and don't know why. I'm writing this code in functions.php

```
    $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $termid = get_term($term, 'product_cat');

    $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
    //echo $cat_id;

    if ($termid->parent > 0) {
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'child_of' => $termid->parent
        );

        echo $termid->parent;


        $term = get_queried_object();
        $parent_id = $term->parent;
        $parent_name = $parent_id->name;
        echo $parent_name;



        $siblingproducts = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
        $nazwa = get_queried_object()->name;
        $slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
        echo '<a href="' . site_url() . '/kategoria-produktu/' . $slug . '">' . $nazwa . ' ';
        foreach ($siblingproducts as $siblingproduct) {
            if ($siblingproduct->term_id == $term) { ?>
                <li>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li>
            <?php } ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($siblingproduct); ?>"><?php echo $siblingproduct->name; ?><?php echo "<span class='count'>" . $siblingproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php }
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'child_of' => $term
        );

        $subproducts = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

        $nazwa = get_queried_object()->name;
        $slug = get_queried_object()->slug;

        echo '<a href="' . site_url() . '/kategoria-produktu/' . $slug . '">' . $nazwa . ' ';
        foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($subproduct); ?>"><?php echo $subproduct->name; ?><?php echo "<span class='count'>" . $subproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php }
    }
```